# How to load Soap response on table view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-4.2

I am working with handling soap request and response.. and I m able to make the server request and also I am getting the server response,which i parsed on uialertview Message,**But when I am trying to load it on a tabelview,I am not able to fill the array with strings,So please help me out**

Below is my code

```
#import "SoapTableViewController.h"


@implementation SoapTableViewController

@synthesize customerArray;
@synthesize webData;
@synthesize dict;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) GetCustomers
{
    NSString *soapMessage =@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
    "<soap:Body>\n"
    "<GetCustomers xmlns=\"http://www.fashionize.ca/\" />\n"
    "</soap:Body>\n"
    "</soap:Envelope>\n";       

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fashionize.ca/Service1.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://www.fashionize.ca/GetCustomers" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}



-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response 
{
    webData =[[NSMutableData data]retain];
    [webData setLength: 0];
}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error
{
    NSLog(@"Error With Connection");
    [webData release];
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] 
                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] 
                        length:[webData length] 
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //---shows the XML---
    NSLog(theXML);
   // [self parseXml:theXML];
    [theXML release];  


       if (xmlParser)
        {
            [xmlParser release];
        }    
        xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
        [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
        [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
        [xmlParser parse];

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict {

    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"])
    {
        if (!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                     }
        elementFound = YES;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (elementFound)
    {
        [soapResults appendString: string];

        [customerArray addObject:soapResults];

    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"])
    {

        //---displays the country---
                [customerArray addObject:soapResults];
        NSLog(soapResults);        
        elementFound = FALSE;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Customer Name!" 


                              message:soapResults 
                              delegate:self  
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [soapResults setString:@""];
        elementFound = FALSE; 


        //[customerArray addObject:soapResults];


    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [webData release];
    [customerArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self GetCustomers];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [customerArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text =[customerArray objectAtIndex:row];
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

here u can see my customer array is empty..so friends and geeks please tell me where i am going wrong..

Thanks and Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

I dont see an alloc for your customer array? If there is no memory for it, it cannot be added to which would hint why its empty.

```
customerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
```

Comment: Hi louie thanks for ypour reply...I wrote ur line of code..but then also it shows that the array is empty..please help me out

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. In `parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser`  reload your table.

```
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
[reload tblView];
}
```